# How do you show the result of an ALTER statement in mysql or pdo using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

When I run queries on the command line, I get a result similar to this:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Is there a way to get the above information using PHP PDO?

Comment: The first two are easy, that's just checking if the query was executed and the affected rows (`mysqli_affected_rows()` for example). Not sure about the rest though.

Comment: @Shadow provided a great answer. When the above information is required, it is easy enough to create a separate mysqli connection instead of PDO, and use `$mysqli->query($sql); echo $mysqli->info;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way because this information is returned by `mysql_info()` C API call (this is the C API, not mysql API deprecated years ago in php, although it did implement the same call), which is not implemented in PDO being too vendor specific.

You can use [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to return the number of affected rows or matched rows. However, the value returned by the method depends on how you configure your connection to mysql:

If you provide `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` as configuration option, then `rowCount()` returns the matched rows:

```
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
```

If you leave this option out, then `rowCount()` returns the affected rows. Therefore there is no easy way to obtain both information in a single connection.

To get the number of warnings you can issue a [show warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-warnings.html) sql statement and loop through its resultset and count the warnings (or perhaps the notes) in the resultset. `show warnings` results include errors and notes as well, this is why you may need to filter the list.

I'm not aware on how you would obtain the number of duplicates for the last statement.

**mysqli**

If you used mysqli instead of PDO, then you could use [mysqli_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php) call to obtain the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

And... Use `microtime(true)` for getting timings.  And execute `SHOW WARNINGS` (as if it were a `SELECT`) to get any warnings (or none).